# Hovering through stacked bar chart using mplcursors

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I have a stacked bar chart in a tkinter tab.

[image]

Here, if I try to hover through the bar using mplcursors. It is showing y-axis values where I need the value of the bar to be displayed

I used

```
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
```

How could I show the effective bar values?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom function to update the annotation. Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib.container import BarContainer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def show_annotation(sel):
    if type(sel.artist) == BarContainer:
        bar = sel.artist[sel.target.index]
        sel.annotation.set_text(f'{sel.artist.get_label()}: {bar.get_height():.1f}')
        sel.annotation.xy = (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2)
        sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.8)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': [10, 20], 'beta': [np.nan, 30], 'gamma': [54, 38], 'delta': [42, 75]},
                   index=['First', 'Second'])

ax = df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, figsize=(15, 5), cmap='inferno')

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
cursor.connect('add', show_annotation)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors with info about stacked bars]